# Mapping rest post request to object

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, rest-assured

My application under tests has endpoint defined like below:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "maxsize", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Void> changeMaxQuoteSize(@RequestBody DataRequest dataRequest,
                                               @AuthenticationPrincipal UserProfile userProfile) {

    orderManager.scheduleUpdateCurrencyConfigRules(dataRequest.getCurrency(),
            (c) -> c.setMaxQuoteSize(dataRequest.getMaxSize()))

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
}
```

I want to sent message to it using rest-assured but my question is how to map request body to DataRequest object ?

I tried it that way:

```
class DateRq {
    private String curpair;
    private Double maxQuoteSize;

    public DateRq(String curpair, Double maxQuoteSize) {
        this.curpair = curpair;
        this.maxQuoteSize = maxQuoteSize;
    }
}

@Test
public void test() {
    String endpoint = "http://127.0.0.1:8095/api/maxsize";

    DateRq request = new DateRq(TICKER_SYMBOL, 5_000_000D);

    Response response = RestAssured.given()
            .when()
            .body(request)
            .post(endpoint);

    assertEquals(200, response.getStatusCode());
}
```

but receive such error:
*com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class com...PMTest$DateRq and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)*

I tried with some kind of JSON but we didn't receive any response:

```
    @Test
public void test() {
    String endpoint = "http://127.0.0.1:8095/api/maxsize";

    String request = new JSONObject()
            .put("curpair", TICKER_SYMBOL)
            .put("maxQuoteSize", 5_000_000D)
            .toString();

    Response response = RestAssured.given()
            .when()
            .body(request)
            .post(endpoint);

    assertEquals(200, response.getStatusCode());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried code like this?

```
DateRq request = new DateRq(TICKER_SYMBOL, 5_000_000D);

Response response = RestAssured.given()
        .body(request)
        .when()
        .post(endpoint);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it changes nothing